# I dont understand part 3 ' Building the Model' of the nerd dinner tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I went through the **Nerd Dinner asp mvc 1** tutorial at [this website](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm).

However, I am using asp mvc 2 although they say to use mvc 1(for some reason I dont think this is an issue), and didnt know where to put the **Retrieving, Updating, Inserting and Deleting using the DinnerRepository class** code. They do say to put in the **DinnerRepository class** but how is it triggered by a button or ....

I also do not know where to put the **PhoneValidator** code also because it is quite unclear to me. And finally **Handling Validation and Business Logic Violations** code. I dont know where exactly it goes in the Nerd Dinner project.

Can someone give me some assistance, if possible, I am really beginning to like mvc.

**Info:** Im using xp sp3, with VS 2010 Professional and asp mvc 2.

Thanks,
...

Comment: Some notes: Download the newest copy of the free book, its over [here](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html) The source code is online and was last updated Feb18-10 here at  http://nerddinner.codeplex.com You can browse the source online and link to a specific file like [this](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61627#874282)

Answer (score 1):

The class files don't have to be in any particular place.

If you are following along on the example and have already created the DinnerRepository class,  you could double-click on the class in the UI and put in all the methods there.   To answer your question about how it is getting triggered at runtime,  they aren't showing that in Part3 (that comes in Part 4 it appears).

For the phone validater,  you can simply create a new class (similar to the steps to create the DinnerRepository class) and put the code in there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I created the DinnerRespository class ok will put all those update , delete methods. Actually phone validator is put in the views folder in the actual completed file. But comparing it with the completed project available for download the phone validater code seems to be incomplete in the tutorial. Thanks for your input. I guess I will work on it and hope it works. tc.